# How to reduce the implementation code of lots of wrapper classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I am developing a library with some classes, let's call them `C1, C2 and ... Cn`. Each of these classes realize some interfaces, i.e. `I1, I2, ... Im.` (n > m). The relationship between objects in the library is complex and I have to 
provide some API for my library users to access these objects using smart pointers.

After some discussions, I found that returning shared pointers to the library users is not a good idea, because in that case I cannot make sure that the object can be removed precisely in my library's memory. Returning weak pointers have the same issue, because if the user of the API `.lock()`s the weak pointer and keep the resulted shared pointer somewhere, I will face the same problem again.

The final idea I have, is to expose some kind of wrappers for the weak pointers. A wrapper class can be something like this:

```
class Wrapper_C1 : public I1
{
   std::weak_ptr<C1> mC1;
public:
   Wrapper_C1() = delete;
   Wrapper_C1(const std::weak_ptr<C1> & c1) : mC1(c1)
   {
   }

   int method1_C1(int x)
   {
       if (auto sp = mC1.lock())
       {
           sp->method1_C1(x);
       }
       else
       {
            throw std::runtime_error("object C1 is not loaded in the lib.");
       }
   }

   void method2_C1(double y)
   {
       if (auto sp = mC1.lock())
       {
           sp->method2_C1(y);
       }
       else
       {
            throw std::runtime_error("object C1 is not loaded in the lib.");
       }
   }

   // The same for other methods
};
```

As you see, all of this wrapper classes, share the same implementation. What is the best way to reduce the code of ALL of these wrapper classes? Is there anyway to avoid repeating the similar codes?

Comment: Do you mean 'refactor'?

Comment: @dandan78 No, I edited the post title.

Comment: Meta-programming ( interface names can be static) or Bridge Design Pattern should be good.

Comment: @seccpur Any examples?

Comment: @Gupta this might be possible with `__declspec(propety` .... this can allow a getter (checkout) and setter (checkin) while still making '.' syntax possible - this would need `clang` or msvc at least

Comment: @darune Looks nice. Do you have any examples of how to use it?

Comment: What do you mean by _I cannot make sure that the object can be unloaded precisely in my library?_ Are you unloading the shared library?

Comment: *"that the object can be unloaded precisely in my library"*. What did you mean? dynamic loading of shared library (`dlsym`/`LoadLibrary`)? Then you might provide wrapper to ensure lifetime of object/library.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I will not unload the shared library. The C1, C2 and Cn objects are part of a graph in the library. The API user may want to unload one object of the graph, in that case some dependent objects of the graph will be removed from the memory of my lib. So, if the user have a shared pointer on them, I cannot ensure that the objects are out of memory then.

Comment: @Jarod42 As I answered to Maxim's comment, All the C1, C2 and Cn objects are part of graph in my lib that can be loaded or unloaded from/into a file. I do not mean library loading here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you drop inheritance in the wrapper, you might do something like the following to factorize all wrappers:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
private:
   std::weak_ptr<T> m;
public:
   Wrapper() = delete;
   Wrapper(const std::weak_ptr<T> & w) : m(w) {}

   auto operator -> () /* const */
   {
       if (auto sp = m.lock())
       {
           return sp;
       }
       else
       {
            throw std::runtime_error("object is not loaded in the lib.");
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: I must admit this is even better than mine ;)

Comment: Wow, looks great.

Comment: `shared_ptr<int> stolen; void func(Wrapper<int> ptr) { stolen = ptr.operator->(); }`

Comment: @firda: Try to guard against Murphy, not Machiavelli :-).

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do without resorting to macros (which also wouldn't help here, to fully resolve your problem we would need some kind of static reflection) is fix these repetitions:

```
if (auto sp = mC1.lock())
{
    sp->method1_C1();
}
else
{
     throw std::Exception("object C1 is not loaded in the lib.");
}
```

What I see you can easily reduce it to template function like this one:

```
template<class T, class R, class... Args>
R call_or_throw(const std::weak_ptr<T>& ptr, const std::string& error, R (T::*fun)(Args...), Args... args) {
    if (auto sp = ptr.lock()) 
    {
        return std::invoke(fun, *sp, args...);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(error.c_str());
    }
}
```

Than you can use it like that:

```
int method1_C1(int x)
{
    return call_or_throw(mC1, "object C1 is not loaded in the lib.", &C1::method1_C1, x);
}

void method2_C1(double y)
{
    return call_or_throw(mC1, "object C1 is not loaded in the lib.", &C1::method2_C1, y);
}
```

You can even make macro out of it

Comment: Looks good, Thanks. It seems that realization of ALL of the methods is unavoidable, right?

Comment: @Gupta yes, it is impossible to autogenerate methods according to some scheme. As I said, you need either static reflection in cpp or static code generator

Answer (score 2):

Using smart-pointers for tree/graph nodes is less than ideal. The tree node destructors destroy the smart-pointers to child nodes and those in turn call child node destructors resulting in recursion which may overflow the stack when the trees are deep or available stack size is small.

An alternative design is to have a tree class that manages the lifetime of its nodes and uses plain pointers, a-la `std::map`. And have a rule that removing a node invalidates pointers and references to the removed sub-tree.

Such a design is simple, robust and most efficient at run-time.

Comment: I created a large binary tree on my machine with 24 levels and `1.67772e+07` nodes, each node contains two shared pointers. This is the biggest tree I can create on my laptop, because with 25 level it cannot allocate memory for shared pointers. While destruction, a takes some time but it does not overflow the stack. The reason is clear, because I will not have more than 24 activation records on top of the stack for calling nested destructors.

Comment: @Gupta With a balanced tree you may get away with that.

Comment: But you are right, if the depth of my tree goes over 750 (for an unbalanced tree), I will have an stack overflow while destruction. Nice point. Thanks ;)